# Angular HTTPInterceptor is not detected

Tags: javascript, angular, http, jwt, interceptor

I am trying to create an angular app that will do requests to the ASP NET CORE WEB API using JWT tokens, I set up a httpinterceptor, but it doesn't seem to work - it doesn't add headers to the requests and the interceptor itself doesn't show up in browser sources. It doesn't do anything.
[image: 401 error]
[image: sources]

The code below is supposed to send requests with authorization headers which contain tokens. It doesn't work, I even tried to write console.log in it, but to no avail.

auth.interceptor.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

    if (token) {
      req = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`),
      });
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

My problem is with getMe() method - it is supposed to return the name of the current user based on token. It works fine in swagger, so it's not backend, register and login methods work fine too, so it's not cors.

AuthService.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public Register(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      'https://localhost:7272/api/Auth/register',
      user
    );
  }

  public Login(user: User): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post('https://localhost:7272/api/Auth/login', user, {
      responseType: 'text',
    });
  }

  public getMe(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:7272/api/Auth', {
      responseType: 'text',
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }
}
```

My app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    HeaderComponent,
    MainMenuComponent,
    RouterLink,
    RouterLinkActive, FormsModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'untitled';
  user = new User();

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  register(user: User) {
    this.authService.Register(user).subscribe();
  }

  login(user: User) {
    this.authService.Login(user).subscribe((token: string) => {
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', token)
    });
  }

  getme() {
    this.authService.getMe().subscribe((name: string) => {
      console.log(name);
    });
  }
}
```

I import every component like so:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxMaskDirective,
    NgxMaskPipe,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    provideNgxMask(),


  ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Method in my backend that is supposed to be executed on request - after going through authorization.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetMyName()
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
        {
            result = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the controller endpoint:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    public static User user = new User();
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public AuthController(IConfiguration configuration, IUserService userService)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet, Authorize]
    public ActionResult<string> GetMe()
    {
        var userName = _userService.GetMyName();
        return Ok(userName);
    }
```

I tried to allow credentials both in backend and frontend, but it doesn't work at all. I tried removing the provideHttpClient() provider, but it doesn't affect anything at all.

Comment: You are providing HttpClient twice in imports and providers!

Comment: Ok, there are two ways to import modules to the project. Use either imports or providers.

Comment: Console the updated headers, and make sure the append method is returning the headers updated headers.

Comment: Also, share the code that you execute the methods.

Comment: Another piece of advice that is applicable to all your coding problems.
- Delete everything 
- Add each piece of your code one by one. 
- And detect which step is causing the problem.

Comment: I added the backend methods in the  OP.

Comment: Check out this repository. https://github.com/AHMET-EMREBAS/techbir/tree/5-todo-auth

Angular App is under apps/client directory

Answer (score 0):

You have declared two instances of the angular HttpClient in your app:

```
@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule, // <-- 1 here
    ...
  ],
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    provideHttpClient(), , // <-- 2 here
  ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

for the interceptor to work you need to only have one.

Try removing `provideHttpClient()` and the interceptor should start working.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I did exactly that before and that didn't help.

Comment: Did you check if you are impoting HttpClientModule or provideHttpClient() anywhere else in your app? Also make sure you stop your app entirely and restart it for the change of removing these to take effect